# Is there an accepted way to adjust this so that all of my `enum class` elements are grouped together in the ClassView?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, enum-class

Old code:

```
typedef enum tagUndoAction { UNDO_CHANGE_CELL = 0,
                             UNDO_CHANGE_SELECTION_START,
                             UNDO_CHANGE_SELECTION_SUB } UNDO_ACTION_E;
```

New code:

```
enum class UndoAction { ChangeCell = 0,
                        ChangeSelectionStart,
                        ChangeSelectionSub } ;
```

In ClassView:

[image]

What I liked about the previous approach was that all of the enumerations were listed together in the ClassView. Now they are displayed A - Z fashion with all the classes.

Is there an accepted way to adjust this so that all of my `enum class` elements are grouped together in the ClassView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is down to personal taste but I have settled on a comporomise of several methods:

1. I have moved some `enum  class definitions` to inside the class that uses it the most.
2. For others I have moved them into a `AppEnums` namespace.

This works for me.